# In cmd.exe, how can you get one variable to escape the setlocal command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scope, cmd

I frequently find myself using `setlocal` within `cmd.exe` to avoid polluting the environment variable space with temporary variables (and to ensure both command extensions and delayed expansion are active).

However, I'm at a loss on how to do this if I actually want one of those variables to be made available.

Consider the following code which gives you the final component of the current directory (so `c:\pax\dir1` would give you `dir1`):

```
        @echo off
    :main
        setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
        call :func
        echo.main_folder = %folder%
        endlocal
        goto :eof

    :func
        setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
        set temp=%cd%
        set folder=
    :funcloop1
        if not "x%temp:~-1%"=="x\" (
            set folder=!temp:~-1!!folder!
            set temp=!temp:~1,-1!
            goto :funcloop1
        )
        echo.func_folder = %folder%
        endlocal
        goto :eof
```

When I run this, I get the output:

```
func_folder = dir1
main_folder =
```

and you can see that the `%folder%` variable does not survive the `endlocal`. However, if I leave off the `setlocal/endlocal` from the function, the `temp` varaible pollutes the namespace of `main`.

I know I can just use `set temp=` at the end of `func` and this will remove the environment variable but that doesn't cover the case where I'm already using that variable in the outside scope (it gets totally destroyed in that case).

Is there a way in `cmd.exe` to allow a select group of environment variables to propogate to the outside scope while still preventing others from affecting it? In other words, can you have both local variables and return variables?

---

Aside, please don't tell me there's a better way of getting the final path component. That is an example case only.

Actually, you *can* tell me a better way since it'd be nice to know but it won't be answering my specific question :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"The solution to this is to take advantage of the fact that the CMD shell evaluates variables on a line-by-line basis - so placing ENDLOCAL on the same line as the SET statement(s) gives the result we want:" source: [ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html)

So changing the endlocal of func: to this...

```
endlocal & set folder=%folder%
```

...will get you the behaviour you want.

Comment: With maybe some more parenthesis thrown in?

Comment: @Ben Not to my knowledge. The ampersand, as used, is a command separator not an operator. Not that using parenthesis would hurt, so if you'd prefer feel free.

Comment: Brilliant. Works perfectly, including multiple `&& set` commands to allow more than one variable to escape.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say quotes, not parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

For better reading and formatting, you can use parentheses.

```
call :func resultVar
echo(%resultVar%
goto :eof

:func 
setlocal
set var=2
(
  endlocal
  if "%1" NEQ "" set "%1=%var%"
  goto :eof
)
```

This works, because a command block will be expanded like a single line.
The parser expands the first two phases (percent variables and escape characters) before executing the command block.
The other phases are executed in time (Like delayed expansion, second expand phase by CALL, ...)

Answer (score 0):

`endlocal && set aaa=%aaa% && set bbb=%bbb%`
permanantly sets `aaa` and `bbb` outside of the `setlocal` and keeps this setting in the command prompt for another batch file to use (for exmaple, if the batch file containing the `setlocal` was called from another batch file the calling batch file will now have the new settings for `aaa` and `bbb`

Thanks to whoever explained about `endlocal && set`. I went through umpteen websites to get a resolution to this straight forward situation.